# jmockit issue when mocked class contains method returning Integer

Tags: java, jmockit

`JMockit` is not returning the `Integer` set as the return value in an expectation.

```
public interface Foo {
    Integer getInt();
}

@Test
public void test(@Mocked final Foo foo) {
    final Integer anyInt = 3;
    new Expectations() {{
        foo.getInt(); result = anyInt;
    }};
    assertThat(foo.getInt(), equalTo(anyInt));
}
```

fails with message:

```
java.lang.AssertionError:
Expected: <3>
  but: was <0>
```

Any idea why?

JMockit 1.14

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JMockit Expectations API has a set of `any` fields for argument matching, including `anyInt`. So, the "`anyInt`" that appears inside the expectation block is that field, *not* the local variable of same name.

(If you are using a decent Java IDE, it should show fields with a different color than that used for local variables, making the mistake easy to spot.)